# Flutter agora video call screen when app is closed

Tags: flutter, background-process, agora.io, videocall

Can someone please share the code how to implement call screen in background with agora? I'm developing a video calling app by following the The CS Guy skype clone series on youtube. Everything is working fine when app is open. I want to show the call screen when app is closed. I've looked everywhere but couldn't find a proper solution or code to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using callkeep. You can read more about it here: https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/call_invite_notification

Comment: I've successfully integrated callkeep but I'm confused how to show call screen to only receiver. Can you please share some code how to do that?